# Find mode of kernel density estimate in GPS data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gis, kernel-density

I'm analyzing GPS location data with weights indicating "importance". This can be easily plotted as heatmap, e.g. in google maps. 
I would like to analyze this using the python data stack and, in particular, want to find the mode of a kernel density estimate.

How can I compute the mode of a KDE in python?

Very specifically, given the example at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_species_kde.html how would you find the location with highest probability of finding the "Bradypus variegatus" species?

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider a simple example of getting kde-estimation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from pylab import plt

np.random.seed(10)

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
kde = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x, y]))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), np.linspace(0, 1, 100))
Z = kde(np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])).reshape(X.shape)

plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, we can get the coordinates X and Y,  where Z takes its maximal value:

```
X.ravel()[np.argmax(Z.ravel())]

0.3535353535353536

Y.ravel()[np.argmax(Z.ravel())]

0.5555555555555556
```

In practice, when estimating locations of highest probability of occurrence some
species, you need not the only one position, but some area around it. 
In this case, you can choose, for example, all locations, where the probability
is greater than 90 percentile of all possible probability values, e.g.

```
Y.ravel()[Z.ravel() > np.percentile(Z, 90)]
X.ravel()[Z.ravel() > np.percentile(Z, 90)]
```

In case  of [cited example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_species_kde.html), you can try the same approach to get desired result. Probably, you will need to tweak threshold value, e.g. choose 75-percentile instead of 90-percentile value.

Comment: This solution samples the KDE on a grid and chooses the highest value - OK but not very efficient. I thought there must be some gradient climb method which converges well, not limited to the grid. This can be seeded in the different locations that are the generating points of the KDE. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Getting largest values should be fast,  `np.argmax, [Z.ravel()>....]` are implemented in C; I suspect that computation of kde is a bottleneck; May be Scikit-Learn kernel density estimator based on `cKDTree` will be efficient enough.